# Java : show web content under condition using MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to show some content in JSP page under some condition:

```
    if(db_controller.getClientNumber()>1){
        out.print("<span>You have <a href=\"View.jsp?type=Client\" style=\"color:#31708f\">" +
                db_controller.getClientNumber()+ 
                    " </a>clients</span>");
    }
```

The problem is, as I'm rewriting my code to fit MVC pattern, I don't know how to handle the conditions.

If I don't do a comparison `if(db_controller.getClientNumber()>1)` in my JSP page, how can I show content (view) according to different conditions?

What is the proper way to do this in MVC design pattern ?

Comment: Any specific MVC framework you're using?

Comment: @Rahul Yadav No, I'm currently rewriting my project to fit MVC without using any framework

Comment: You can write this logic in controller instead of jsp, which will redirect to view when specific condition is satisfied.

Comment: Show us your MVC code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSP Expression Language (EL) like shown [here](https://dzone.com/refcardz/essential-jsp-expression)